# Should I mention recognition awards I have received at any point in the interview process?

Tags: interviewing

I have received two monetary recognition awards at my current employer.  These were for apps that I was the sole developer on.  I am currently looking for a new job.  Should I mention the awards when I am talking about the projects I have worked on during the interview process?

Comment: Sure. I would even consider adding them to the CV. Why do you think it might not be a good idea?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere and why is that? The award is the one which is of the value, not the prize money associated with it.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere they are surely different from the category of developing something as an Individual contributor on a codebase? being nice and promoting diversity and encouraging CSR activities - gift cards are given for any/all of them, but they are not awards based on the actual work responsibilities, are they?

Answer (score 6):

Don't wait for the interview.

The goal of the cover letter and the resume is to get you to an interview. Anything that you can put into those documents, that makes a positive impression, can't hurt. Do this especially if the award is relevant for the position you are applying for.

Be prepared to talk about the awards at the interview. As long as explaining it doesn't make it sound unimpressive, put it in the resume/cover letter.

Also have a plan for working it into the interview if they don't ask about them.

Answer (score 4):

If the awards aren't a company trade secret, why not? Keep in mind that other employers don't know anything about the process how these awards work. So either explain it in very short form in your CV, or just mention it in a very general form and elaborate in the interview.

Example: "Company A Design Award": How many employees are in the ranking? Why did you receive that award? How often is the Award given away? "How big is the fuss"?

Answer (score 0):

Like so many other things when switching employers (such as title or salary), the potential new employer will have extremely limited insight into the exact meaning. They may not even care.

Keep it as a line-item on your resume or cover letter. Be prepared to discuss it in more detail if it's asked about.

Think of it as ribbons on a military uniform. Any amount is impressive but the details are rarely important. But again, be prepared to explain them in dialogue, because having a bad or incomplete answer is going to sink the entire interview.